# $n\ge 5$, prove $A_n$ is the only non-trivial proper normal subgroup of $S_n$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups, permutation-cycles

Given than $A_n$ is simple for $n\ge 5$, prove $A_n$ is the only non-trivial proper normal subgroup of $S_n$.

My work:

Assume it is false, then there exists some non-trivial proper normal subgroup $K$ of $S_n$, where $K\neq A_n$. We know $A_n$ is a normal subgroup of $S_n$. Let $T=K\cap A_n$, hence $T$ is a normal subgroup of $S_n$, which implies $T$ is a normal subgroup of $A_n$, namely,

$$\{e\}\mathrel{\unlhd}T\mathrel{\unlhd}A_n\mathrel{\unlhd}S_n$$

So $T=\{e\}$ or $T=A_n$, otherwise $A_n$ is not simple.

(1) If $T=A_n$, it implies $A_n\subseteq K$. Since the index $[S_n: A_n]=2$, $A_n$ is the maximal proper subgroup of $S_n$, hence $K=A_n$, which contradicts with $K\neq A_n$.

(2) If $T=\{e\}$, it implies that all elements in $K$ are odd permutations (except the identity element $e$). But

$$\text{odd permutation}\cdot \text{odd permutation}=\text{even permutation}$$

so for any non-identity elements $a, b\in K$, we have $ab=e$, since $e$ is the only even permutation elements in $K$.

(i) If $|K|\ge 3$, then $K=\{e, a, b, \dots \}$, and $ab=e=aa\Longrightarrow a=b$, contradicts with $a\neq b$.

(ii) If $|K|=2$, then $K=\{e, a\}$, and $|a|=2$,

**I am not sure about the following argument:**

First we write $a$ as disjoint cycles, such as

$$a=(1,2,3)(6,9, 17, 8)...(., .,)$$

The number appears only once in the $(.,.)$. For example, it never happens like $(1,2)(1,3)$. In this case, $1$ appears twice, and we will simplify it as $(1,3,2)$. But this will lead to the order of $|a|\ge 3$, which contradicts with the fact that $|a|=2$.

Since the element $a$ has order $2$, we can simplify $a$ as the distinct disjoint transpositions, and each number appears only once, such as

$$a=(1,2)(i,j)...(p, q)$$

If $3$ doesn't appear in any of transposition $(.,.)$ of $a$, then we take an element $(1,2,3)$ from $S_n$ we have $(1,2)(1,2,3)\neq (1,2,3)(1,2)$

If $3$ appears in some transposition $(3,k)$ of $a$, we have $(1,2)(3,k)(1,2,3)\neq (1,2,3)(1,2)(3,k)$

Therefore, $K$ is not normal and we reach a contradiction.

Comment: In case 2, $K$ has order 2, so it is central. Show that $S_n$ has trivial center.

Comment: That's not a duplicate. This question asks for a proof using a certain fact, @BrauerSuzuki.

Comment: The composition of two odd *permutations* is *even*, @BrauerSuzuki.

Comment: Good point. But the proof in the linked question follows exactly the same line (the fact that $A_n$ is simple is used behind the curtains).

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki No, this link didn't answer my question.

Comment: This is not duplicated, do not close it!

Comment: Since $|A_n||K|/|T|=|A_n K|\le|S_n|$, we have $|K|=2$. Hence, $K$ is central. Now follow the solution in die linked question.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki I am NOT asking how to prove it. I am asking about my proof.

Comment: I don't see any question in your post.

Comment: thank you! @BrauerSuzuki

Comment: For "solution-verification", you must not only say "I am not sure about this part", you must explicitly state *which* **specific** step you are unsure about, and **why**.  I don't see either of these, but rather simply a multi-step argument prefaced with "I am not sure about [this]". Which **step** are you unsure about, and *why?*